# How to get a list of logical drives?

Tags: c++, multiplatform

How can I get list of logical drives in C++? I know that for Windows in C# is a function `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()`, but that's Windows only solution. Is there any multiplatform way? I went through a Boost::Filesystem documentation, but found nothing.

Comment: Other platforms don't necessarily have the concept of drive.

Comment: It's a Windows-only solution to a Windows-only problem.

Comment: Please, define *precisely* what you mean by "logical drive". If you mean what I think you mean, then those simply don't exist on systems other than Windows (and Windows clones such as ReactOS) and a few niche systems that evolved from or were inspired by CP/M, so there simply cannot possibly be a multiplatform way that works on non-Windows systems. E.g. neither of macOS, Linux, BSD, Unix, BeOS, i/OS, OS/390, and so on have that concept.

Comment: You'll be shocked to learn that other operating systems do not have anything at all that's equivalent to this concept of drive letters, that dates back to (pre) MS-DOS days. That's because other operating systems did not evolve from MS-DOS, of course, and therefore do not have to suffer its legacy. As such, there is no "multiplatform" solution, since there's nothing to solve in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, you probably misunderstood me. I need get the "entry point" to the drives/volumes. In Linux this is /run/media/USER/drive-name (Fedora), in Windows this is the drive letter (ex. C:\\). I have no idea how this is on macOS (Is it similiar to Linux?). I need only mounted volumes.

Comment: @RichardZavodny What you see in Linux is not an exact equivalence. In Linux "drives" (actually *partitions*) are not filesystem roots like they are in Windows. They exist at a lower level than the abstract filesystem that Linux presents to the application. Partitions are *mounted* onto the global abstract filesystem tree and they can be mounted anywhere (not just in `/run/media/user/...`). So it really depends on what you need this information for? There is no cross platform way to address specific drive partitions that I know of.

Comment: Please, define *precisely* what you mean by "entry point".

Comment: I explained it above. The absolute path to the drive root. Let's say, you have following file structure on your drive: 

/some.txt
/image.jpg
/my-folder/another-image.png
/my-folder-two/another-text-file.txt

I need get path to the /. There could be more than one drive. In Windows, this entry points are handled using drive letters (C:\, D:\, ...), at Fedora linux, this is handled like this: /run/media/USER/drive-name. I don't know how much drives on the system is, that's the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

C# and .Net are not just for Windows any more.  The [DriveInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=netcore-2.0) is part of .NET Standard 2.0, and so is available cross-platform with .NET Core 2.0.